# Python exclude directory with fnmatch

Tags: python-2.7, pattern-matching, wildcard

I'm working with some legacy code that I can't change (for reasons).

It uses `fnmatch.fnmatch` to filter a list of paths, like so (simplified):

```
import fnmatch

paths = ['a/x.txt', 'b/y.txt']

for path in paths:
  if fnmatch.fnmatch(path, '*.txt'):
    print 'do things'
```

Via configuration I am able to change the pattern used to match the files. I need to exclude everything in `b/`, is that possible?

From reading the docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) it does not appear to be, but I thought asking was worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

From the fnmatch.fnmatch documentation:

> Patterns are Unix shell style:
>
> > *       matches everything
> >
> > ?       matches any single character
> >
> > [seq]   matches any character in seq
> >
> > [!seq]  matches any char not in seq

When I run:

```
for path in paths:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(path, '[!b]*'):
        print path
```

I get:

```
a/x.txt
```

Comment: `[!b]` will also prevent things like `books/abc.txt` to be matched.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow this method works for alphabet just after "!'

for example in my case from the list **col_names**

*['# Spec No', 'Name', 'Date (DD/MM/YYYY)', 'Time (hh:mm:ss)', 'Year',
       'Fractional day', 'Fractional time', 'Scans', 'Tint', 'SZA',
       'NO2_UV.RMS', 'NO2_UV.RefZm', 'NO2_UV.RefNumber', 'NO2_UV.SlCol(bro)',
       'NO2_UV.SlErr(bro)', 'NO2_UV.SlCol(ring)', 'NO2_UV.SlErr(ring)',
       'NO2_UV.SlCol(HCHO)', 'NO2_UV.SlErr(HCHO)', 'NO2_UV.SlCol(O4)',
       'NO2_UV.SlErr(O4)', 'NO2_UV.SlCol(O3a)', 'NO2_UV.SlErr(O3a)',
       'NO2_UV.SlCol(O3223k)', 'NO2_UV.SlErr(O3223k)', 'NO2_UV.SlCol(NO2)',
       'NO2_UV.SlErr(NO2)', 'NO2_UV.SlCol(no2a)', 'NO2_UV.SlErr(no2a)',
       'NO2_UV.Offset (Constant)', 'NO2_UV.Err(Offset (Constant))',
       'NO2_UV.Offset (Order 1)', 'NO2_UV.Err(Offset (Order 1))',
       'NO2_UV.Shift(Spectrum)', 'NO2_UV.Stretch(Spectrum)1',
       'NO2_UV.Stretch(Spectrum)2', 'HCHO.RMS', 'HCHO.RefZm', 'HCHO.RefNumber',
       'HCHO.SlCol(bro)', 'HCHO.SlErr(bro)', 'HCHO.SlCol(ring)',
       'HCHO.SlErr(ring)', 'HCHO.SlCol(HCHO)', 'HCHO.SlErr(HCHO)',
       'HCHO.SlCol(O4)', 'HCHO.SlErr(O4)', 'HCHO.SlCol(O3a)',
       'HCHO.SlErr(O3a)', 'HCHO.SlCol(O3223k)', 'HCHO.SlErr(O3223k)',
       'HCHO.SlCol(NO2)', 'HCHO.SlErr(NO2)', 'HCHO.Offset (Constant)',
       'HCHO.Err(Offset (Constant))', 'HCHO.Offset (Order 1)',
       'HCHO.Err(Offset (Order 1))', 'HCHO.Shift(Spectrum)',
       'HCHO.Stretch(Spectrum)1', 'HCHO.Stretch(Spectrum)2', 'Fluxes 318',
       'Fluxes 330', 'Fluxes 390', 'Fluxes 440']*
I wanted to search all the names that did not contain NO2_UV.
If I do

```
header_hcho = fnmatch.filter(col_names, '[!NO2_UV.]*');
```

it excludes the second element that is "Name"., because it starts with N. And the result is the same as if i do

```
header_hcho = fnmatch.filter(col_names, '[!N]*');
```

So, I went by rather an old-school method

```
header_hcho = []
idx=0
for idx in range(0, len(col_names)):
    if col_names[idx].find("NO2_UV") == -1:
        header_hcho.append(col_names[idx])
    idx=idx+1
```